# Render another collection for each 2 records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Job` and `Project` models.
I need to render project record after each 2 jobs. Having 2 AR collections: `@jobs` and `@projects`

For example:

```
Job 1
Job 2
Project 1
Job 3
Job 4
Project 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you always getting 2n jobs and n projects? Or at some point you might not have enough jobs to render all projecst?

Comment: Are the jobs related to the projects you're interleaving them with?

Comment: @Leito sometimes there is not enough jobs, but projects must be there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209125/render-another-collection-for-each-2-records-in-rails#comment58136221_35209344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= @jobs.each_with_index do |job, index| %> <!-- index starts from 0 -->
   <%= job %> # render job
   <%- if index % 2 == 1 -%> <!-- for Job with ids 2, 4, 6, ... -->
      <%= @projects[index/2] %> <!-- render project -->
   <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

- Job 1, index = 0

  - `index%2 = 0` => no project shown
- Job 2, index = 1

  - `index%2 = 1` => project shown after job
  - Project 1
- ....

Comment: `0 % 1` is `0`. So you will get `job .. project .. job .. project ... job ..job ..project

Comment: Thanks @Jon I have fixed that issue

Comment: In addition to your recent update ... `anything % 1` is always `0`. So no projects will ever be displayed.

Comment: You need to use something like `if index % 2 == 1` ... and then there's no need to worry about it being greater than `0`

Comment: Thanks for solution guys. What if there is only one `job` ? I need the rest of projects to be displayed. Replace `@jobs.each_with_index` to `25.times_with_index` ? (25 is the default jobs count per page)